# custom bodyDecoder for Express in node.js server

Tags: javascript, api, node.js, express

I'm trying to figure out how to override the Express.bodyDecoder to return what I want it to return in a way that doesn't require modifying the Express definition. I feel like I could implement it right now but I don't know the "right way". Help?

Answer (score 2):

You can copy the [Connect bodyParser](https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/blob/master/lib/middleware/bodyParser.js) (which is passed up through Express) and modify it to taste, then call your modified version rather than express's in your app configuration.  Example:

```
var express = require('express'),
    myBodyParser = require('myBodyParser');

var app = express.createServer(
    myBodyParser()
);
```